# Teamspeak 2 sound trouble

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, teamspeak

i have a teamspeak 2 installed on ubuntu 18.04.1.

When i started it i realized that is use `oss /dev/dsp device`.

[image: Picture of settings in ts].

So, when i try to `padsp teamspeak`.

I have breaking voice, recording lags and bad sound quality(especially when i load pc hard(flight-sim).
Any ideas how to make it work without lags and freezes?
TeamSpeak is very important part of online-flight so i wanna ATC to hear me load&clear

Comment: Keep in mind that TS2 has been obsoleted by TeamSpeak 3 for a LONG TIME now - this was done by the upstream.  TS2 didn't have a lot of codec support and such that TS3 does.

Comment: I would be interested in  getting this to work as well. Same issue. 
And I know there is TS3, but there is software that is only compatible with TS2 so far and hence there is no way to use TS3.

Comment: @BenjB, fixed it! Check the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
TS2 works perfectly with osspd emulation.

To install we need to build proxy daemon from source:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/osspd/ossp-1.3.2.tar.gz
tar -zxvf ossp-1.3.2.tar.gz
cd ossp-1.3.2/
make
sudo make install
```

If you get an error like that

```
No package 'fuse' found
gcc -Wall   -o osspd osspd.c  -L. -lossp 
osspd.c:14:27: fatal error: cuse_lowlevel.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Then you have to install `libfuse-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev
```

Next, make up from downloaded source:

```
cd ossp-1.3.2/
make
sudo make install
```

Ready!

To enable that type in terminal

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/osspd
sudo chmod o+rw /dev/dsp /dev/adsp /dev/cuse /dev/mixer
```

Found from [here](https://anton.logvinenko.site/ru/blog/oss-proxy-daemon-emulyatsiya-oss-zvukovogo-ustroystva.html)